# From Bootstrap 4 collapse events, is it possible to extract which elements have been hidden/shown?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'd like to add some additional functionality to a Bootstrap 4 accordion, and am considering using their events (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events). However, from their example,

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

It seems that no information is passed into the callback function.

I would like to know *which* element(s) were shown or hidden. Do I understand correctly that this is not possible using the `.bs.collapse` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event that the shown/hidden element is simply accessible as `this` in the callback function. A little experiment with the debugger shows that this is indeed the case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is way late in the game but maybe someone will have benefit.  For any of the 4 events you should be able to do something similar (in this case I want the **id** of the element that is being shown:

```
$('#accordionProperty').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    CallingSomeFunctionOfMineWithId(e.target.id);
})
```

And for hidden:

```
$('#accordionProperty').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    CallingSomeFunctionOfMineWithId(e.target.id);
})
```

Hope this helps.